# How to stay in the same angular page after a page refresh?

Tags: angular, redirect, routes

When I refresh my angular web page, angular app takes me automatically to the home page and also when I copy and paste an Url, angular app goes automatically to home page.

I want to stay in the same page after doing a page refresh or paste the Url in the address bar.

I am using angular 7 with AdalGuard class

This is the routing code

```
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AdalGuard] },
  { path: 'meal/:id', component: MealDetails, , canActivate: [AdalGuard]},
  { path: 'coldmeal/:id/:page', component: ColdMealComponent, canActivate: [AdalGuard]},  
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My app.module.ts has HashLocationStrategy:

`providers: [ { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ]`

I am expecting to stay in the same page after a page refresh or after pasting the Url in address web bar.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if this is not the solution you need! If it isn't, Ill try to help more

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy

Comment: Hi @FranciscoSantorelli I am using HashLocationStrategy  and my app.module.ts looks like: providers: [    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ] and it still not working

Comment: have you tried using cookies?

Comment: @PatoVargas I am not sure if the cookies caused that issue. Any suggestion how I can use cookies to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by replacing HashLocationStrategy with PathLocationStrategy in app.module.ts file.

`providers: [ { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy } ]`

Now I can refresh the page without losing it.