After implementing guards for routes, the pages are not reloading
The guard I shared below controls access to routes based on the user's role. Since we started using this guard, whenever we refresh pages in the browser or try to load pages with URL information, it redirects to the index.html page.
The current URL information appears as "/" in the currentUrl . For some reason, the route information is lost when the page is refreshed.
This issue only occures when the page is refreshed, when I navigate between pages, the components are loading.
The Route Access Control Guard:
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  const user = this._authService._user?.profile.sub;
  const route = next.routeConfig?.path?.split('/')[0];
  const currentUrl = this._router.url;


  return this.hasRight(user, route);
}

private hasRight(currentUserId: any, route: any): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
  return new Promise<boolean | UrlTree>((resolve, reject) => {
    this._securityService.apiSecurityHasRightPost(currentUserId, route).subscribe(
      (response: BooleanResponse) => {
        if (response.result!) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(this._router.createUrlTree(['/unauthorized']));
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error', error);
        resolve(false);
      }
    );
  });}

I apply this guard to routes as shown below.
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'test', component: NewtestpageComponent,canActivate:[RouteAccessControlGuard]},
            { path: 'redirect', component: MainRedirectComponent },
            { path: 'brand', component: BrandComponent,canActivate:[RouteAccessControlGuard]  },

]}]

The base href in index.html page: <base href="/">
The app-routing-module:
const AUTH_ROUTES: Routes= [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'unauthorized', pathMatch:'full'}, 
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
  { path: 'signin-callback', component: SigninCallbackComponent },
  { path: 'signout-callback', component: SignoutCallbackComponent },
  { path: 'silent-callback', component: SilentCallbackComponent },
]
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'main', pathMatch:'full'}, 
  { path: '', component: AuthLayoutComponent, children:AUTH_ROUTES}, 
  { path: 'main',loadChildren: ()=>import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule), canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'showroom/:id', component: ShowroomComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  })]

I restructured the asynchronous setup in different ways, thinking that the issue might be related to timing. I moved the hasRight method into a service and a resolver, but it didn't solved the issue.

Hi, do you have the same behavior when you copy/paste the url in the address bar ?
I hope this link may help you => https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419534/8404545

Hi, yes, I do have the same behavior. but changing the path location strategy didnt solve the issue. we use two guards for all routes, the AuthGuard doesnt cause such issue, the pages are loading as expected when refreshed but when I apply RouteAccessGuard to routes Im starting to face this issue.  the two guards have the same working logic, they send request to the servers and receiving a boolean response.

And If you try to remove onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'

unfortunately, doesnt change anything.
